# Add Fancybox in Magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2.4, requirejs, requirejs-config.js, fancybox

First, I added these files to my custom theme:

- app/design/frontend/Custom/mytheme/web/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js
- app/design/frontend/Custom/mytheme/web/css/jquery.fancybox.css

Then I edited `app/design/frontend/Custom/mytheme/requirejs-config.js`, like this:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            html5shiv: 'js/html5shiv',
            responsive: 'js/responsive',
            theme: 'js/theme'
        }
    },
    paths: {
        'fancybox': "js/jquery.fancybox.min"
    },
    shim: {
        'fancybox': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

and in `app/design/frontend/Custom/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` I added:

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
...
<head>
    <css src="css/jquery.fancybox.css" />
</head>
...
</page>
```

After all this, I still cannot use fancybox. The following code, placed in product page phtml file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery','fancybox'], function($) {
        Fancybox.bind("[data-fancybox]", {
          // Your options go here
        });
    })
</script>
```

returns javascript error:
**fancybox is undefined**

Can you help me fix this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are importing `fancybox` but then using difference case in your code - `Fancybox`.

Failing that try adding your fancybox path within the `map` config instead of path.

```
map: {
        '*': {
            html5shiv: 'js/html5shiv',
            responsive: 'js/responsive',
            theme: 'js/theme',
            fancybox: 'js/jquery.fancybox.min'
        }
}
```

Comment: I tried both, but I'm still getting error. Js/css files are loaded in page. There's some kind of trouble with require js. Is there a way to use a fancybox without it?

Comment: `Fancybox.bind` this should remain like this, using uppercase for first letter